# SFTP con Genexus 17 y archivo de clave

Tags: genexus

alguien a trabajado con sftp en genexus pero solicitando archivo de claves al conectar con el servicio SFTP. me refiero a lo siguiente: me entregan un archivo sin extencion que contiene la clave de acceso al SFTP y con ese mas el host, usuario y puerto deberia conectarme al SFTP, lo hice mediante filezilla y conecta, busque en la ayuda de gx y salen los comandos para realizar esto, pero no hay un ejemplo ya que no funciona lo indicado.

esta es la info que encontre:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?44967,Connection+Options+SFTP

de ante mano gracias.

saludos!

Comment: Estás en Linux o Windows?, Independiente de eso puedes usar el cliente ssh para conectarte o el winscp para windows

Comment: Hola, es una aplicacion web windows.

Comment: https://youtu.be/NO92-qh9X00

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. ya hice eso y me funciona bien, lo que necesito es poder desde genexus realizar una aplicacion en la que me conecte al SFTP con el archivo de la clave. Saludos!

Comment: Ok, ok, estaba viendo la documentación y esa cosa es súper ambigua, sorry no podría ayudarte con eso. Es un api sin programación, es como un rompecabezas para ciegos 

Comment: Muchas gracias de todas maneras por tus respuestas. saludos!